# sql 'where like' clause not returning data when multiple languages in records

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

picture shows full column records but i want the last record only. how to achieve that

Comment: Define "last" .. ? In RDBMS there are no first or last rows unless you define an order.

Comment: i mean 5th record. that record in my local language tamil. i did the following Select productName from Products  
where productName like '%ம%'

Comment: Again. 5th record in what order? In RDBMS, rows are an unordered set.

Comment: You mean you want the product which has that Tamil character?

Comment: yes excatly i want to return that tamil character record.

Comment: In the future, please copy/paste the text of your sample data or results into the question. It is considered very rude here to post images of data.

Comment: ya sure, i too feel the same. i am fairly new to this forum. i will correct this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
where productName like N'%ம%'
```

The `N` prefix in front of `'%ம%'` indicates an `nvarchar` literal, which supports unicode characters, instead of a `varchar` literal, which does not handle unicode well at all.

Comment: thanks brother its working fine. thanks a lot. you saved me lot of time n effort. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Select Top 1 productName from Products where productName like %LD%

Comment: thanks for the reply @lazyboy but that letter is not english, its tamil.

Comment: please post your full sql clause.

Comment: Select productName from Products  
where productName like '%ம%'